# How can I create a temp file and delete it after a certain amount of time

Tags: ruby, file, time

I want to create a file using (possibly) Ruby's `tempfile` library, however I want this file to last around 30 minutes.

For example:

```
require 'tempfile'

def create_tempfile
  temp = Tempfile.new('file')
  temp.write('test')
  path = temp.path
  strt_time = Time.now
  end_time = Time.now - start_time

  if strt_time - end_time <= 1800
    temp.unlink
  else
    # do something to make the file last 30 minutes
  end
end
```

I'm not sure that the above will do anything, but it gets the point across. So my question is, is there a way I can have a file, be it `temp` or text, last only thirty minutes, and then get deleted, or wiped? Currently I'm running Windows 7

Comment: `sleep(60*30)` will do that. Put it in a separate thread if you have other things to do while you wait for the file to be deleted, but as @Nabeel says, `cron` is the way to go here.

Comment: Why do you need that file around for 30 minutes? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: @spickermann I can't actually tell you the reason why I need the file around for that specific amount of time, but I can tell you it has to do with a program that copies to the clipboard, I want the file to be accessible in case you overwrite the clipboard with something else if you know what I mean? The catch is that the information _CANNOT BE CACHED OVERNIGHT_ so I need a backup for a certain amount of time in order to achieve what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible unless you want the Ruby script to run for 30 minutes. It might be easier to store the file in a specific folder (such as `/tmp`) and have a Cron job automatically wipe files older than a certain time.

Comment: I'd love to use a `cron` job, I probably should have specified that I'm running Winodws 7

Comment: Windows has a task scheduler :), you could invoke any script of your liking. Here's a link that might help: http://www.howtogeek.com/201930/how-to-automatically-delete-files-in-your-download-folder-on-a-schedule/.

Comment: Files stored in the `/tmp` directory are automatically garbage collected when the reference is lost.

Answer (score 2):

The [Tempfile documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html#class-Tempfile-label-Explicit+close) has this example showing how to cause a file to be deleted:

> Explicit close
>
> When a Tempfile object is garbage collected, or when the Ruby interpreter exits, its associated temporary file is automatically deleted. This means that’s it’s unnecessary to explicitly delete a Tempfile after use, though it’s good practice to do so: not explicitly deleting unused Tempfiles can potentially leave behind large amounts of tempfiles on the filesystem until they’re garbage collected. The existence of these temp files can make it harder to determine a new Tempfile filename.
>
> Therefore, one should always call unlink or close in an ensure block, like this:

```
file = Tempfile.new('foo')
begin
   ...do something with file...
ensure
   file.close
   file.unlink   # deletes the temp file
end
```

You could use a [Timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) to force the file's close, or you could `sleep 60 * 30` after creating the file inside the `begin` block.

Comment: Would running the `sleep 60 * 30` in a single thread force my program to stay running? Or is there a way I could run it in the background?